# Choosing smooth structures on topological manifolds

Tags: differential-topology

Let $A$ be the category of closed connected topological manifolds that admit at least one $C^{\infty}$-structure. Let $B$ be the category of closed connected $C^{\infty}$-manifolds.

There is a forgetful functor $B\rightarrow A$. Is there a reasonably explicit functor $A\rightarrow B$ such that the composition $A\rightarrow A$ is naturally isomorphic to to the identity functor?

This question is not really motivated by anything external, move along if you are not interested.

Comment: You're asking, in part, if the group homomorphism $\text{Diff}(M) \to \text{Homeo}(M)$ has a section. [Necessarily](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02688v1) any homomorphism $F_*: \text{Homeo}(M) \to \text{Diff}(M)$ is continuous. In particular if the composite $\text{Diff}(M) \hookrightarrow \text{Homeo}(M) \xrightarrow{F_*} \text{Diff}(M)$ is the identity, then the composite $\text{Homeo}(M) \xrightarrow{F_*} \text{Diff}(M) \to \text{Homeo}(M)$ is the identity map on a dense subset, and so is equal to the identity; but this composite has image contained in $\text{Diff}(M)$, a contradiction.

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you! Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Given that the answer by Mike Miller doesn't seem completely obvious/elementary (at least for a non differential topologist etc), why all those downvotes?

Comment: @Qfwfq As a non differential topologist but as a category theorist, I found it obvious.

Comment: Presumably the assertion that this question isn't motivated by anything could also be a source.  This is a basic question in manifold theory and there's substantial literature on it.   But you'll have to strip-away the category theoretic language to find the literature.

Comment: @ToddTrimble you mean you already knew the reference Mike Miller provided?

Comment: @RyanBudney but in some sense nothing is motivated by anything (you have to arbitrarily choose some set of statements you care about and then anything related to them would be motivated by them). Though I understand if my interests are not popular and may deserve downvotes.

Comment: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4200/flood-of-similar-new-users

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Dear Steven Landsburg, could you please not link this discussion to my questions? I am a different person from whomever is the cardinal and I do not see how you linking this here is helpful.